# What do those constants mean in the Align tool?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

By default, in the Align tool, 'Horizontally in Container or Vertically in Container' are set to 0. What does '0' mean?

Answer (score 0):

Using Align tool, you can center the view in the superview either horizontally, vertically or both.Some time you just need to set the subviews to the center, in this case you do not need to set leading trailing constraint, well in run time it depend on you needs.

By default it set to 0 means centre alignment.

For example here i have added a label which is always center in the ViewController:

[image]

You can also change the center like:

[image]